# Create 'raw' assembly code with gcc(Intel syntax)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, intel-syntax

I want to create some assembly code with gcc. When I use `gcc -masm=intel -S test.c` I get assembly code full of `.def` and `.cfi` labels which I cannot assemble. Is there a way to create assembly code without this labels?

E.g.: A simple c code like:

```
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.file   "test.c"
.intel_syntax noprefix
.def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
.text
.globl  _main
.def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB0:
.cfi_startproc
push    ebp
.cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
.cfi_offset 5, -8
mov ebp, esp
.cfi_def_cfa_register 5
and esp, -16
call    ___main
mov eax, 0
leave
.cfi_restore 5
.cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
ret
.cfi_endproc
LFE0:
```

But what I want is something like:

```
_main:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    and esp, -16
    call    ___main
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

I hope there's a way to do this. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Probably you cannot. gcc produces assembly intended for the gnu assembler - Which will assemble your first example fine. Which assembler are you using ? You can probably get rid of the directives with  `cat main.s | grep -v '^\s*\.'` though.

Comment: @nos I use nasm and some other assemblers using nasm syntax.

Comment: @nos I'm not sure if I need them, but if not your solution should work fine.

Comment: You can always use a perl script to clean up the output

Comment: CFI is Call Frame Information. It's used by debuggers, and possibly for exception unwinding, but you don't need it in ordinary C.